# Hook that fires when admin setting is saved

Tags: hooks

Is there any specific hook that fires when admin setting is saved. I have cached some data from admin back-end setting menu. Now i want to the delete the caching when setting saved in admin menu. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is the *filter* `'pre_update_option_' . $option`. You have to know the option name. Options can be updated from front-end too, so WordPress doesn’t make a difference here.

Then there is an *action*: `'update_option'`, you get the arguments `$option`, `$oldvalue` and `$_newvalue`.

Finally, if the update went successful, you get two further actions:

```
do_action( "update_option_{$option}", $oldvalue, $_newvalue );
do_action( 'updated_option', $option, $oldvalue, $_newvalue );
```

See the source code of `update_option()` for details.

Comment: Thanks toscho for the help, I looked into the update_option source code and tracked it down.

Comment: As of WordPress 4.4 the action `update_option` has three (3) parameters. `do_action("update_option_{$option}", $oldvalue, $value, $option);`