# Updating post_meta when updating a setting with the Settings API

Tags: post-meta, settings-api

I'm currently using the Settings API and, on saving my options group, I need to simultaneously update post_meta based on the options that have been saved.  Is there anywhere within the Settings API that I can hook to some sort of save action (with access to the options value etc) in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After even more searching I've found an answer to this question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59336/45290).  I used the `update_option_{$option_name}` action to do what I needed.