# add_option_{$option} action hook not being called

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions, settings-api

I'm trying to write some files to the server when the settings for my plugin are saved. I'm using the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) and a class that looks like -

```
class AAPF_Admin {

  public function __construct() {

    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'aapf_options_page'));

    /* Register the settings when the options pages are initialized */
    if ( !empty($GLOBALS['pagenow']) and 
       ( 'options-general.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'] || 
         'options.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) ) {
      add_action( 'admin_init', array($this, 'aapf_register_settings'));
    }

    /* This is what I'm unable to make work */
    /* I've tried  
       add_option_aapf
       add_option_aapf_options
       add_option_aapf-options
       add_option_aapf_main_settings
       add_option_aapf_field_sandbox
    */
    add_action( 'add_option_aapf_options', function( $a, $b ) {

      // write some files to the server...

    }, 10, 2 );

  }

  /* Adds the settings page for this form */
  public function aapf_options_page() {

    add_options_page( 
      'Page Title',                                 // Page Title
      'Menu Title',                                 // Menu Title
      'manage_options',                             // Capability
      'aapf-options',                               // Menu Slug
      array($this, 'aapf_options_page_html')        // Callback
    );

  }

  public function aapf_register_settings() {

    register_setting( 'aapf', 'aapf_options' ); // option group, option name

    add_settings_section(
      'aapf_main_settings',                       // id, used in form tag on admin screen
      __( 'Settings', 'aapf' ),                   // title or the section
      array($this, 'aapf_settings_callback'),        // callback
      'aapf'                                      // page to display on
    );

    // ... register settings fields ...

  }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would be really grateful. Thanks!

Edit: I have seen [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177272/hook-if-somebody-saves-plugin-options) and [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59335/hook-that-fires-when-admin-setting-is-saved) and they got me on the right track, but I'm still having this problem.

Comment: `add_option_{$option}` is firing inside `add_option` function, so I am guessing you have to add some options first with `add_option` function.

Comment: from my understanding [`register_setting`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) adds options, and uses `add_option` to update them

Comment: I don't see any calls to `add_option` inside [`register_setting` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-includes/option.php#L1871)

Comment: as mentioned in the accepted answer to the 2nd question you site in your edited question, you should be hooking into `update_option_aapf_options` and not `add_option_aapf_options`.  Using the Settings API, the function hooked to `add_option_aapf_options` will only be called the **first** time you save changes on your settings page.