# Hooking into button when using Settings API

Tags: settings-api

I'm making use of the Settings API for a WordPress plugin. However, I want to perform some processing after the "Save Settings" button has been pressed (which I'm adding via the `submit_button` function.

However, whereas I'd normally check `$_POST` to detect if the form has been submitted and therefore perform my action, this doesn't appear to work for the API.

Is anybody aware of a simple way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hook that fires when admin setting is saved](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59335/hook-that-fires-when-admin-setting-is-saved). Here is the option saved before redirecting back to the settings page you submitted from: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-admin/options.php#L339